# SQL Server 2000 Error Creating Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I can't create a function in SQL Server 2000 in my database. So, I tried to use the example in the help (F1), but I have the same error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CubicVolume
    -- Input dimensions in centimeters
   (@CubeLength decimal(4,1), 
    @CubeWidth decimal(4,1),
    @CubeHeight decimal(4,1) 
   )
RETURNS decimal(12,3) -- Cubic Centimeters.
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( @CubeLength * @CubeWidth * @CubeHeight )
END
```

Errors:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Line 2:
> Incorrect syntax near 'FUNCTION'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Must declare the variable '@CubeLength'.

I run this script for Database Northwind and it didn't have problem, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: One **major** problem is the **way oooooooold** version of SQL Server you're using. This has been out of even extended support for several years now - ***HIGHEST*** time to upgrade!

Comment: @marc_s what does "highest time to upgrade" mean?

Comment: I can´t, I need to use SQL 2000. I don´t know why I can´t use this script in my database, but in Northwind works succesfully.

Comment: Check the compatibility level of the database where it's not working. I bet it's from before the invention of UDFs.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can check that, please?

Comment: Search the database property pages for the compatibility level as suggested here

Comment: `EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname = N'your_database_name';` - update it with `EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname = N'your_database_name', @new_cmptlevel = 80;`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers.

The problem was resolved.

The problem was compatibility on the level as Aaron Bertrand said.

Click Right on Database -->Properties-->Options-->Compatibility Level

(Needs 80 or high)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk4lX.png)